# connect Windows 8 client to Mac OS X Server Fileshare

Tags: macos, server.app, windows, file-sharing, smb

I want to connect a Windows 8 Client to a SMB fileshare on a OS X Server 10.9. With OS X I have no problems, but I don't know what I have to do to get the Windows client connected.

Comment: Did you get an error Message on the Client or Server? If so, please post it.

Comment: try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152906/85275

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Windows 8 Client is using SMBv3 but your 10.9 Server is using SMBv2. There is a Tech-Note on the Microsoft-Support Site (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-uk/kb/2686098)) which suggests disabling the Security-Negotiation Settings, f.e. either manually set the required flag in the Registry:

```
"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters"

RequireSecureNegotiate -Value 0 -Force
```

or running the following command in the PowerShell:

```
Set-SmbClientConfiguration -RequireSecuritySignature $true
```