# Macbook 10.11.5 all of a sudden can't login to Windows shared drive

Tags: macos, mac, windows, server.app

I had absolutely no problems for months. When I first got it I did command+K and typed in the ip address of the server, then put in the admin login for the window server and all three shared drives on the server were there to connect and mount...

Now when I connect to the same IP address (the ip address is the same this is verified) it DOES ask me for the username and password, but it will not take any of the logins. I've remoted into the server and even added another admin account, but it still wont let me login... obviously it sees the server or it wouldn't ask for credentials. This happened very suddenly and I've made no specific changes on the server. the shared folders are shared with permissions to everyone full access...

does anyone have any recommendations? this is driving me insane

Comment: Does this help - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152900/share-mac-files-yosemite-with-windows/152906#152906

Comment: No, because they're trying to get to shared folder from Windows to files on a mac. I'm trying to get to my shared folder on my windows from my macbook. And it worked perfectly until a bit ago... it sees the share but wont let me login even though the login is fine